# .net does ArrayList.Clear free up memory?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I have a heavily populated arraylist, which I want to clear and reuse. If I clear it will it free up that previously used memory?

I should also mention that the arraylist is a private read only field of a class that still has lots of active work to do after I use the arraylist first time round. So I can't wait for garbage collection after class goes out of scope.

Is the Clear method fast enough? Or should I destroy and create a new arraylist?

Question update:

If I have field declared like this (thanks to Jon's advice)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of tasks.
    /// </summary>
    private List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
```

then I populate it.... (heavily)

Now if instead of clearing it and trimming, can I just call:

```
tasks = new List<Task>();
```

Would this be recommended?

Comment: +1 for Jon as he's covered it really.  However, Clear will not really free memory anyway - only the Garbage Collector does that.

Correctly written IDisposable objects also free unmanaged memory in their implementation of Dispose - if applicable.

Perhaps I'm just being pedantic though :)

Comment: Good point Andras, but I think its sufficient to have that mem ready for garbage collection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do whichever expresses your intention better. Do you *actually* want a new list? If so, create a new one. If you conceptually want to reuse the same list, call `Clear`.

The documentation for `ArrayList` does state that [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.clear.aspx) retains the original capacity - so you'll still have a large array, but it'll be full of nulls instead of reference to the previous elements:

> `Capacity` remains unchanged. To reset
>   the capacity of the `ArrayList`, call
>   `TrimToSize` or set the `Capacity`
>   property directly. Trimming an empty
>   `ArrayList` sets the capacity of the
>   `ArrayList` to the default capacity.

Any reason you're using `ArrayList` rather than `List<T>` by the way?

Comment: Hi Jon, to answer your question lack of knowledge I guess, what is the benefit of using List<T>?

Comment: @JL: Generic collections are generally better: type safe at compile-time, easier to use (no need for casts), more efficient for value types... what version of .NET are you using? (They're only available from .NET 2.0 and upwards.)

Comment: Last q: If I had a heavily populate List<T> and after using it set its value to new List<T> (obviously where T = my class) - would this give me a new List<T> and at the same time free up previously used memory for garbage collection?

Comment: It would make the previous list eligible for garbage collection if nothing else had a reference to it, yes. It wouldn't actually force the garbage collector to run, of course - but usually that's a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the memory to actually be free'd, set it to null and invoke the garbage collector.  Then create a new ArrayList.  If you set it to null and then create a new one, it will eventually get garbage collected when additional memory is required.  Also, I second generic collections.  It's been a long time now since I've used ArrayList.

Comment: I agree on GC.Free(), I avoid it.  However, I've seen instances where it is necessary.  I have read techniques on using it in XNA games between scenes to avoid garbage collection at the wrong time in a game...it has its uses.